# Pivotal Cloud Foundry Installation of Elastic Runtime Fails at smoke tests

Tags: cloud-foundry

vSphere 5.5

Ops Manager 1.3.4.0

Elastic Runtime 1.3.4.0

Ops Metrics 1.3.3.0

Install fails on step: Running errand Run Smoke Tests for Pivotal Elastic Runtime

I can't go into the VM to troubleshoot what is going on, as when smoke tests fail the smoke tests vm is removed.  I can skip the smoke test errand and it will complete, but I am trying to figure out why the smoke test errand will not complete properly.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a complete link to my install log https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14091323/cf-install.log

Here is an excerpt from the install log where the failure happens:

```
Errand push-app-usage-service' completed successfully (exit code 0)
{"type": "step_finished", "id": "errands.running.cf-9b93ae0464e2a248f279.push-app-usage-service"}
{"type": "step_started", "id": "errands.running.cf-9b93ae0464e2a248f279.smoke-tests"}
46ab6197-dd49-46f1-9631-1249406d452f
Deployment set to/var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments/cf-9b93ae0464e2a248f279.yml'

Director task 52
Deprecation: Please use templates' when specifying multiple templates for a job.template' for multiple templates will soon be unsupported.

Deprecation: Please use templates' when specifying multiple templates for a job.template' for multiple templates will soon be unsupported.

Deprecation: Please use templates' when specifying multiple templates for a job.template' for multiple templates will soon be unsupported.

Deprecation: Please use templates' when specifying multiple templates for a job.template' for multiple templates will soon be unsupported.

Deprecation: Please use templates' when specifying multiple templates for a job.template' for multiple templates will soon be unsupported.

Deprecation: Please use templates' when specifying multiple templates for a job.template' for multiple templates will soon be unsupported.

Started preparing deployment
Started preparing deployment > Binding deployment. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding releases. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding existing deployment. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding resource pools. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding stemcells. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding templates. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding properties. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding unallocated VMs. Done (00:00:00)
Started preparing deployment > Binding instance networks. Done (00:00:00)
Done preparing deployment (00:00:00)

Started preparing package compilation > Finding packages to compile. Done (00:00:00)

Started creating bound missing vms > smoke-tests/0. Done (00:00:37)

Started binding instance vms > smoke-tests/0. Done (00:00:00)

Started updating job smoke-tests > smoke-tests/0 (canary). Done (00:00:45)

Started running errand > smoke-tests/0. Done (00:00:38)

Started fetching logs for smoke-tests/0 > Finding and packing log files. Done (00:00:01)

Started deleting errand instances smoke-tests > vm-0207c40c-3551-4436-834d-7037871efdb5. Done (00:00:05)

Task 52 done

Started 2015-04-12 21:23:27 UTC
Finished 2015-04-12 21:25:36 UTC
Duration 00:02:09

Errand `smoke-tests' completed with error (exit code 1)[stdout]
################################################################################################################
go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64
CONFIG=/var/vcap/jobs/smoke-tests/bin/config.json
{
"suitename" : "CFSMOKETESTS",
"api" : "https://api.cf.lab.local",
"appsdomain" : "cf.lab.local",
"user" : "smoketests",
"password" : "ad445f38ca9bbf21933e",
"org" : "CFSMOKETESTORG",
"space" : "CFSMOKETESTSPACE",
"useexistingorg" : false,
"useexistingspace" : false,
"loggingapp" : "",
"runtimeapp" : "",
"skipsslvalidation": true
}CONFIG=/var/vcap/jobs/smoke-tests/bin/config.json
GOPATH=/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace:/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests
GOROOT=/var/vcap/data/packages/golang/aa5f90f06ada376085414bfc0c56c8cd67abba9c.1-f892239e5c78542d10f4d8f098d9b892c0b27bc1
OLDPWD=/var/vcap/bosh
PATH=/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/_workspace/bin:/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/bin:/var/vcap/packages/cli/bin:/var/vcap/data/packages/golang/aa5f90f06ada376085414bfc0c56c8cd67abba9c.1-f892239e5c78542d10f4d8f098d9b892c0b27bc1/bin:/var/vcap/packages/git/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests
SHLVL=1
TMPDIR=/var/vcap/data/tmp
_=/usr/bin/env
################################################################################################################
Running smoke tests...
/var/vcap/data/packages/golang/aa5f90f06ada376085414bfc0c56c8cd67abba9c.1-f892239e5c78542d10f4d8f098d9b892c0b27bc1/bin/go

Running Suite: CF-Smoke-Tests

Random Seed: [1m1428873898[0m
Will run [1m2[0m of [1m2[0m specs

[0mLoggregator:[0m 
[1mcan see app messages in the logs[0m
[37m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/loggregator_test.go:37[0m

[32m> cf api https://api.cf.lab.local --skip-ssl-validation [0m
Setting api endpoint to https://api.cf.lab.local...
FAILED
i/o timeout

[32m> cf delete-space CFSMOKETEST_SPACE -f [0m
No API endpoint targeted. Use 'cf login' or 'cf api' to target an endpoint.

[91m[1m• Failure [5.240 seconds][0m
[91m[1mLoggregator: [BeforeEach][0m
[90m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/loggregatortest.go:38[0m
can see app messages in the logs
[90m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/loggregatortest.go:37[0m

[91mExpected
<int>: 1
to match exit code:
<int>: 0[0m

/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-test-helpers/cf/asuser.go:39
[90m------------------------------[0m
[0mRuntime:[0m 
[1mcan be pushed, scaled and deleted[0m
[37m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/runtime_test.go:62[0m

[32m> cf api https://api.cf.lab.local --skip-ssl-validation [0m
Setting api endpoint to https://api.cf.lab.local...
OK

API endpoint: https://api.cf.lab.local (API version: 2.13.0)

Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.

[32m> cf auth smoke_tests ad445f38ca9bbf21933e [0m
API endpoint: https://api.cf.lab.local
Authenticating...
OK
Use 'cf target' to view or set your target org and space

[32m> cf create-quota CFSMOKETESTORGQUOTA -m 10G -r 10 -s 2 [0m
Creating quota CFSMOKETESTORGQUOTA as smoke_tests...
FAILED
i/o timeout

[32m> cf delete-space CFSMOKETEST_SPACE -f [0m
FAILED
No org targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG' to target an org.

[91m[1m• Failure [15.910 seconds][0m
[91m[1mRuntime: [BeforeEach][0m
[90m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/runtimetest.go:63[0m
can be pushed, scaled and deleted
[90m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/runtimetest.go:62[0m

[91mExpected
<int>: 1
to match exit code:
<int>: 0[0m

/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/init_test.go:59
[90m------------------------------[0m

[91m[1mSummarizing 2 Failures:[0m

[91m[1m[Fail] [0m[91m[1m[BeforeEach] Loggregator: [0m[0mcan see app messages in the logs [0m
[37m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-test-helpers/cf/asuser.go:39[0m

[91m[1m[Fail] [0m[91m[1m[BeforeEach] Runtime: [0m[0mcan be pushed, scaled and deleted [0m
[37m/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/smoke/init_test.go:59[0m

[1m[91mRan 2 of 2 Specs in 21.151 seconds[0m
[1m[91mFAIL![0m -- [32m[1m0 Passed[0m | [91m[1m2 Failed[0m | [33m[1m0 Pending[0m | [36m[1m0 Skipped[0m --- FAIL: TestSmokeTests (21.15 seconds)
FAIL

Ginkgo ran 1 suite in 31.489423576s
Test Suite Failed
Smoke Tests Complete; exit status: 1

[stderr]
+ which go
+ localgopath=/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace
+ mkdir -p /var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace/bin
+ export GOPATH=/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace:/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace:/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests
+ export PATH=/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/workspace/bin:/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-smoke-tests/Godeps/_workspace/bin:/var/vcap/packages/smoke-tests/bin:/var/vcap/packages/cli/bin:/var/vcap/data/packages/golang/aa5f90f06ada376085414bfc0c56c8cd67abba9c.1-f892239e5c78542d10f4d8f098d9b892c0b27bc1/bin:/var/vcap/packages/git/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ go install -v github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
io
bytes
bufio
syscall
time
os
fmt
flag
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/config
go/token
strings
path/filepath
go/scanner
go/ast
path
regexp/syntax
regexp
io/ioutil
net/url
text/template/parse
text/template
go/doc
go/parser
log
go/build
text/tabwriter
go/printer
go/format
os/exec
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo/convert
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo/nodot
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo/testsuite
encoding/base64
encoding/json
encoding/xml
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/types
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/reporters/stenographer
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/reporters
hash
crypto
crypto/md5
encoding/binary
net
compress/flate
hash/crc32
compress/gzip
crypto/cipher
crypto/aes
crypto/des
math/big
crypto/elliptic
crypto/ecdsa
crypto/hmac
crypto/rand
crypto/rc4
crypto/rsa
crypto/sha1
crypto/sha256
crypto/dsa
encoding/asn1
crypto/x509/pkix
encoding/hex
encoding/pem
crypto/x509
crypto/tls
mime
net/textproto
mime/multipart
net/http
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/remote
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo/testrunner
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo/watch
os/signal
github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
+ ginkgo -r -v -slowSpecThreshold=300

{"type": "step_finished", "id": "errands.running.cf-9b93ae0464e2a248f279.smoke-tests"}
Exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in Pivotal Cloud Foundry 1.3.  You will only see this bug if you use a separate Deployment and Infrastructure network (as is recommended).  This bug is fixed in Pivotal Cloud Foundry 1.4.

I have outlined in detail what was going on here:
http://www.feeny.org/smoke-tests-fail-pivotal-cloud-foundry-1-3-solution/

Basically, the short of it is, the smoke-tests errand is created with the Ops Manager Infrastructure network IP address in its /etc/resolv.conf.  This creates an asymmetrical routing situation and results in a timeout.  This can be fixed by changing the following on the Ops Mgr:

To change this behaviour in Pivotal CF v1.3.x, on the Ops Manager VM, change /home/tempest-web/tempest/app/models/tempest/manifests/network_section.rb

```
Line 20: "dns" => [microbosh_dns_ip] + network.parsed_dns,

to "dns" => network.parsed_dns,
```

then restart the tempest-web service:

```
sudo service tempest-web stop
sudo service tempest-web start
```

Now you can re-enable the smoke-tests errand and re-apply changes and all will be well!